# access contents of an array of structs after malloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char, malloc

I am trying store the words and number of each word in an array of `struct word`

```
struct word{
    char str[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    int num;
}

inputFile = fopen("wordstat.txt", mode);
if(inputFile == NULL){
    printf("Cannot open file\n");
    return 1;
}

//scan through file to count number of possible words
while(fscanf(inputFile, "%s", scan)){
    wordCount++;
}

rewind(inputFile);

struct word *words = malloc(wordCount * (sizeof *words));
```

How do i access and store a string of characters into the member variable str? Does it need to be initialized before i do the malloc?

Comment: You don't have to initialize the `str` values if you plan to set them all before accessing them, but if you might not assign every `str` then you may want to use `calloc` instead to zero everything out.  It's a little slower and isn't necessary if you're going to write values later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct word *words = malloc(wordCount * (sizeof *words));
```

effectively creates a one-dimensional array of `word` structures, which you can access either using array notation: `words[i].str`, or pointer notation `(words + i)->str` to get access to entry 'i'.

To store a string of characters (like returned from your `scanf` call), copy them into one of your `word` structures

```
fscanf( inputFile, "%s", scan );
strncpy( words[i].str, scan, MAX_WORD_LENGTH );
```

The memory for the string in each of your `struct word` is allocated when you do the malloc.

Comment: This is the only correct answer.  Arrays are not assignable in C.  You must use `strcpy` or (preferred) `strncpy` as @radical7 indicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `words` as a pointer or array:

```
words[0]
```

Is the first struct.

```
words[0].str
```

Is the first word. And to iterate over all the words:

```
for (int iWord = 0; iWord < wordCount; ++iWord)
{
    // words[iWord] is the current word
    printf("%s", words[iWord].str);
}
```

If you prefer pointers (in this case I don't), then:

```
(words+5)->str
```

Is this 6th word (remember we start numbering at 0). But you might use a pointer like this:

```
for (struct word *pWord = words; pWord < words+wordCount; ++pWord)
{
    // pWord is the current word
    printf("%s", pWord->str);
}
```

Comment: That's what i thought but i get this compile error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[(unsigned int)MAX_WORD_LENGTH]' from type '

Comment: What line is giving an error? And what's the rest of the error? In C you don't assign strings, you have to copy them `strcpy(words[iWord].str, curWord);`

Answer (score 0):

First off, that last line should be

```
struct word *words = malloc(wordCount * sizeof(word));
```

You need the size of the word struct, not the variable which you're declaring on this line...

Beyond that, what you'll need to do is initialize each struct in `words` to some sensible default values, like so:

```
words[0].num = 0; // or any values you please, really
words[0].str[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: Good catch on the `sizeof` mistake.